# Android app sign in only with google (without email option)

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I'm creating an app that signs in users with google sign in. I was wondering, do all android users that downloaded my app (from google play store) have a google account? I want the user to do as little non app-related actions as possible at the onboarding stage and google sign in just solves this corner for me but if not everyone has a google account then I'd have to make an alternative email & password option..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not highly comfortable with server side and devOps, and all you want is just signup-login, I think the best option is to use Firebase [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and I highly recommend it.

From docs

> Firebase Authentication provides backend services, easy-to-use SDKs, and ready-made UI libraries to authenticate users to your app. It supports authentication using passwords, phone numbers, popular federated identity providers like Google, Facebook and Twitter, and more.

And it is free for email and google login you mentioned. And only costs if you used phone verification when exceeds the monthly limit. See pricing [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

Comment: I'm a backend developer so "not comfortable" is more accurate to say about the front end development... I'm building my own backend so firebase isn't an option. I asked only is there a need in an alternative way to sign in because in an iphone the iCloud token always exist (no other way to install the app) so no need for email... I **do not** intend on supporting non google play installation at this time so i guess the real question is "can an app be installed from google play without a google accont present on the phone?"

Comment: @HarryZalessky "can an app be installed from google play without a google account present on the phone?" **NO**, in order to download apps(most probably even just open play store) you must login first using your google account.